# Is Nintendo 3DS online server choice based on console region lock

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

What I mean is that if I take my Australian 3DS (New 3DS XL to be specific) to another region and try to play online, will I be automatically connected with the local (eg US, SEA, EU) server or will my 3DS connect back home to AUS and give me huge latency?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

i believe its depends on what region the game is from, so a japanese game would always connect to the japanese server (although in a different region you will experience a little lag as the servers are further away) i would ask you to research it more as i could be wrong